# Bootstrap Modal from 3.3.2 to 3.3.5 problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap Modal from 3.3.2 to 3.3.5 problems, i have an issue when updating where the modal, is hiding underneath the translucent background

How can I get the z-index correct?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="User-dropdown"      href="#">
    <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/member.php?action=login" onclick="$('#quick_login').modal({ fadeDuration: 250, keepelement: true, zIndex: (typeof modal_zindex !== 'undefined' ? modal_zindex : 9999) }); return false;" class="login">
```

Comment: try to change `modal_zindex : 9999` to `modal_zindex : 1040` or  `modal_zindex : 1050`

Comment: why so low? is the higher value the one on top?

Comment: my bad, I didn't check the code properly, what you are missing is `position` property because z-index only applies to elements that have been given an explicit position, and `z-index : 1050` is the bootstrap modal default property.

Comment: thanks position:absolute or relative? and where do i put it in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a bug in bootstap 3.3.5 modal....

the modal is hiding under the underlay

If i use 3.3.2 CSS with 3.3.5 JS you get the modal without the underlay

If you use 3.3.5 CSS with 3.3.2 JS nothing works

OR VICE VERSA i cannot remember...giving up testing it :P